# How to use Ruby on Rails Mustache to preview in HTML from ActiveModel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, activemodel, mustache

We are using [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache) templates and I would like to make a preview View in our RoR web application that combines a template and some data we have stored in our database, but it does not work as I expected and after some searching on the internets (including SO!), I didn't find any examples that included an active model.

**How do you pipe the ActiveModel records to Mustache to merge with a template?**

The setup:

The Schema

```
create_table "templates", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "kind"
  t.text     "data"
  t.integer  "data_count"
end
create_table "bars", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "guid"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "summary"
end
```

There is nothing special about the models. Both are subclassed from ActiveRecord::Base

```
class Bars < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Templates < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The Controller

```
class TemplateController < ApplicationController
  def preview
    @result = Mustache.render( template.data, :bars => Bar.limit(template.data_count ) ).html_safe
  end
end
```

The View

```
<%= @result %>
```

The Route

```
get 'templates/:id/preview' => 'templates#preview', :as => 'templates_preview'
```

The Data

```
y Bar.all

--- 
- !ruby/object:Bar
  attributes: 
    guid: "1"
    name: "test1"
- !ruby/object:Bar
  attributes: 
    guid: "2"
    name: "test2"
```

The Template (i've simplified the html for example purposes)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  {{#bars}}
    <a href="{{guid}}">{{name}}</a>
  {{/bars}}
</body>
</html>
```

The Result

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href=""></a>
</body>
</html>
```

The Expectation

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="1">test1</a><a href="2">test2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping there is an easy answer to this and I am just missing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it work if you change your controller to:

```
@result = Mustache.render( template.data, :bars => Bar.limit(template.data_count).all ).html_safe
```

(added a call to `.all` after `Bar.limit(template.data_count)`)

I'm pretty new to Mustache, but [glancing *very quickly* through the code](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/blob/master/lib/mustache/generator.rb#L108) seems to show that it  calls this for a section:

```
v = [v] unless v.is_a?(Array) || defined?(Enumerator) && v.is_a?(Enumerator)
```

`Bar.limit(template.data_count)` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is neither an `Array` nor an `Enumerator`. Calling `.all` on the relation turns it into an array and *should* cause Mustache to pass it into the section accordingly.

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. Thanks. That was in fact the problem.